# Advantage of using After in Alter statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any advantage in using **After** and **Before** in alter statement ?

```
Alter table emp add lastname varchar(10) AFTER firstname;
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: none. it just lets you specify where in the table defintion your new field should appear. if you don't specify one, it'll just get slapped on at the end. a specific location would only be useful if you're doing stupid*ahem* silly stuff like `select *` and refering to the fields by numeric position instead of name.

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle doesn't support `AFTER` but MySQL does...

Comment: Just needed to understand is there any performance impact .

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance.